# Is it possible to make client Javascript to become sync on demand

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, v8, interpreter

Why client JavaScript is asynchronous with HTTP requests? Can't it just pass execution flow to interpreter and wait for its call to be picked up from stack and execution to be resumed?

Is it technically impossible to implement?

Comment: AJAX requests take time to be processed, we don't want the UI to be blocked while this is happening.

Comment: "*Can't it just pass execution flow to interpreter and wait for its call to be picked up from stack and execution to be resumed?*" - that's exactly what the `await` keyword does with promises: it picks up the execution *asynchronously*.

Comment: Everyone else has already said why, but I'll add that the asynchronous nature of Javascript (and the "event loop" that underlies it) is the very reason why NodeJS exists, because this behaviour can be very useful on the server side as well. It allows the server to serve multiple requests at once without needing multiple threads.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Sorry, but there is nothing asynchronous about JavaScript. That's not in its nature. **In fact, the JavaScript call stack is, by design and definition, synchronous.** The asynchronous behavior comes from the host's APIs. The event loop is not the very reason that Node.js exists.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Just to be clear (and it's a common misconception), the event loop is not a part of JavaScript. It's a separate component implemented within the host environment. When you do an AJAX call or use `window.setTimeout()`, for example, you are calling out to the the browser to find its `XHRHttpRequest` implementation or its `window.setTimeout` implementation and utilize them. But neither the XHR or `window` are JavaScript objects. The JS runtime has no knowledge of exactly what they are or how they work. They do their jobs outside of the JS runtime.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks for the clarification. I'm still very much learning all this and appreciate being called out on my misunderstandings :)

Comment: Correction on above comment... Should be `XMLHttpRequest` not `XHRHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 4):

> Why client JavaScript is asynchronous with HTTP requests?

If it wasn't, users would have to have their web pages load one resource at a time and page load times would increase dramatically. Who would want that?

> Is it technically impossible to implement?

No, it's not impossible, you could load each resource with an AJAX request that was configured for a synchronous call. But again, I ask, who would want that?

In addition to slowing load times, the UI would be blocked (frozen) until the synchronous operations complete. With modern web pages, you would essentially be creating a frozen screen that takes a long time to render and unfreeze.

If you need operations to happen one after the other, use Promises.